# Session Timeout in Forms based Authentication on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I am trying to use Forms Based Authentication for my Classic ASP application deployed on IIS 7.5. I have a login page which take user entered user name and password and authenticates against Active Directory and sends user to application if authenticated.

In global.asa file, I am putting a variable in Session in the Session_OnStart method.

Sub Session_OnStart
   Session("Timeout") = 1
End Sub

In My asp include page which exists on all my screens I have the below meta-tag which works fine.

Below is Web.config file..The server side session time out does not seem to be working. 
The Session state still exists(When I print Session("Timeout") it still has the value 1), after the one minute..Please advise. FYI, I am not using the LDAP Membership provider, just writing code for it at the moment. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. Please advise!

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>

<system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">           
        <forms cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" loginUrl="Login.asp" name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" requireSSL="false" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>


    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>

    <identity impersonate="false" />

    <sessionState cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" mode="InProc" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" timeout="1" />
```

Comment: man you gotta read about .net, iis and classic asp first. you are mixing two completely different things here...

Comment: Well..the application I am supporting is written in classic ASP and was on IIS 6.0 having basic authentication about 12 years ago. We were asked to upgrade to IIS 7.5 and use forms authentication authenticating against Avtive Directory directly. Since moving to 7.5 means we can support .Net 4.0 I thought maybe adding forms authentication using .Net 4 would be alright. Please let me know if you see any issues with that. We do not have time to rewrite everything.